# anyone got android debug bridge on nikon s800c to linux host working?

Tags: android, adb, udev

OK, I have a brand new Nikon S800c android camera I want to develop a specialized camera app for, and I can't seem to get it to show up in an "adb devices" command. It is USB ID 04b0:018f. I definitely see activity when monitoring events with udevadm and enabling or disabling USB debugging on the camera, but it never shows up as a device adb knows about. Is there something in the SDK or linux that needs updating to know about brand new devices? I did add a udev rule to make it mode 666 and even tried the adb command as root, but it never shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the magic seems to be creating the ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file and putting the 0x04b0 values in it (just on a line by itself). I guess Nikon is a new enough maker of android devices that the stock adb doesn't know about that vendor. Got this answer over in the google android discuss group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-discuss/ky_YMMxPxQ4